# Printf is throwing warning instead of error in below code

Tags: c, printf

Why is the compiler producing only a warning rather than an error for this incorrect program?

```
int main(){
    int a=3,b=4;
    printf("%d,%d");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the ones it was marked duplicate of

Comment: The others are about the behavior of printf when it has too few arguments. This question is about the behavior of the compiler in failing to diagnose what the OP sees as an error. It's not a very well-written question but it's not a duplicate.

Comment: A compiler is not *required* to test any input string argument for possible format errors. What if you write a similar function that uses other string formatting arguments?

Comment: Neither fits. This question has nothing to do with the behavior of printf when the call happens but the behavior of the compiler when you compile the program.

Comment: @P.P.: Similar content **in the answer** does not make a **question** a duplicate.

Comment: @P.P. I am very new to this platform (stack overflow)..I just wrote that statement in an ide and got the "warning:printf has too few argument".i expected an error.By the way,compiler was gcc. and I actually meant why compiler behaved in that way.I will try to improve my question asking skills in future ahead.

Answer (score 5):

Your program has undefined behavior. Since `printf` is a variadic function, there is no constraint violation here, so the compiler is not even required to produce a warning, much less an error. It cannot produce an error except possibly in the case where it can prove the statement invoking undefined behavior is reached during any execution of the program; in your case that's true but it's only true in minimal toy examples and not worth trying to special-case.

Note that for non-variadic functions, a call with the wrong number of arguments is a constraint violation, meaning that the compiler is required to warn ("produce a diagnostic") and arguably should produce an error and refuse to compile the program.